# List of key value lists to dictionary of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have tried this so many times but unable to find answer!
So please help me find any logic to get this answer.

```
main={}
abc=[["1",("1A",'1B','1C')], ['1',('1D','1E','1F')], ['2',('2A','2B','2C')], ['2',('2D','2E','2F')], ["3",('3A','3B','3C')]]

# I WANT main DICTIONARY AS
main={'1':[("1A",'1B','1C'),('1D','1E','1F')], '2':[('2A','2B','2C'),('2D','2E','2F')], '3':[('3A','3B','3C')]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate through the loop and add key, value pairs to the main dictionary.

There might be a more elegant way of doing this, but I think a simple for loop is more explicit.

```
abc=[["1",("1A",'1B','1C')], ['1',('1D','1E','1F')], ['2',('2A','2B','2C')], ['2',('2D','2E','2F')], ["3",('3A','3B','3C')]]

main = {}

for item in abc:
    if item[0] not in main:
        main[item[0]] = [item[1]]
    else:
        main[item[0]].append(item[1])
```

Answer (score 5):

A simple loop with a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) should do:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for k,l in abc:
    d[k].append(l)

print(d)
defaultdict(list,
            {'1': [('1A', '1B', '1C'), ('1D', '1E', '1F')],
             '2': [('2A', '2B', '2C'), ('2D', '2E', '2F')],
             '3': [('3A', '3B', '3C')]})
```

Or if you want to use python's `dict`, you can use `setdefault` to set an empty list as default value if the key does not exist and then `append`:

```
d = dict()
for k,l in abc:
    d.setdefault(k, []).append(l)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
main = {}
for x in abc:
    if x[0] not in main:
        main[x[0]] = []
    main[x[0]].append(x[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner

```
main = {x[0]: [y[1] for y in abc if y[0] == x[0]] for x in abc}
```